# Magento 1.9 Widget Display Recent Sold items

Tags: magento-1.9, product, widget

I need to display a js carousel in frontend with last sold products in Magento 1.9

I build a widget, I found the above code, but this code displays only name and date, I need to found all parameters (url, thumbnail, reviews etc) so I can build the carousel.

```
protected function _toHtml() {


 $itemsCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(5);

foreach($itemsCollection as $item) {
echo $item->getName() . ' - ' . $item->getData('created_at') . '</br>';
}

}
```

Is posible with that code to get other parameters like images, links and other or need something else.

**UPDATE:**

I decide to display the widget with a custom template. I found that code but is not displaying the last sold but only the bestselling.

```
<?php

    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addViewsCount();
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    $products->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
    $this->setProductCollection($products);

?>
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
 <div class=" most_viewed">
 <?php $_collectionSize = 5; ?>
 <ul class="products-grid" id="products-grid-table">
<?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
<li id="td_<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i%5==0 or $i==$_collectionSize){echo 'class="last"';} ?> >
    <div id="cont_<?php echo $i;?>">        
        <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
        </a>
        <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
        <div class="a-center">                        
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="availability"><span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <ul class="add-to-links">
                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                <li class="last"><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<?php $i++; endforeach; $kol = $_collectionSize; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I used

```
  ->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
```

Comment: add `$item->getSku()` in foreach loop of `$itemCollection` and load `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$item->getSku());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself the solution, this code works for me.

```
 <?php

 $storeID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
 $itemsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
->join('order', 'order_id=entity_id')
->addFieldToFilter('main_table.store_id', array('eq'=>$storeID))
->setOrder('main_table.created_at','desc')
->setPageSize(12);
$itemsCollection->getSelect()->group(`main_table`.'product_id');
$products = array();
if(sizeof($itemsCollection)>0)
{
foreach ($itemsCollection as $item) {
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->load($item->getProductId());

?>

 <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image')) ?>">
 <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(122, 109); ?>" width="122" height="109" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image')) ?>" /></a>
 <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, 'short') ?>

  <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($product->getName()) ?>
  <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>')"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>

  <?php
  }
  }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$products = array();    
foreach($itemsCollection as $item) {
echo $item->getName() . ' - ' . $item->getData('created_at') . '</br>';
$products[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$it‌​em->getSku());

}
```

use your `$products` array in carousal.

Comment: Not works, its broke the page.

Comment: @GeorgeGeorge check now.. edit `$products = array();  `

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: I updated my question, check please.

Comment: its report collection it will get only best selling as it is